# SSH to EC2 instance using boto on private IP through bastion server

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to execute some bash script on EC2 instance using `boto`. Boto provides a way SSH to EC2 instance on public IP but in my case the instances have only private IP. The way SSH is done on these instance is using a host which can SSH on all the instance using private IP (Bastion host).
Following is the script to connect to instance on public IP:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_client.download_file('mybucket','key/mykey.pem', '/tmp/mykey.pem')
k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("/tmp/mykey.pem")
c = paramiko.SSHClient()
c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
host=event
print "Connecting to " + host
c.connect( hostname = host, username = "ec2-user", pkey = k )
```

How to connect to instances if `host` have private IP instead of public key if we want to connect through bastion host with public IP `P.P.P.P`

Comment: Where are you running the script? On your own computer on the Internet, or on an Amazon EC2 instance? If EC2, is it in the same VPC? If it is outside of EC2 and you are trying to connect to instances in private subnets, then you need to SSH into the public instance, then somehow initiate another SSH connection from there into the private instances.

Comment: Yes, there is an instance to which I need to ssh first then from this instance I will ssh to instance in private subnet. How this could be achieved in the above script using paramiko.

Comment: You can't do this. You would need to SSH into a public-facing instance, then initiate another SSH session from the Public instance to the Private instance.

Comment: Did you setup any "redirect" or ssh tunneling service in your bastion host?

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to trigger execution of some code on an Amazon EC2 instance, then it would be better to use the [Amazon EC2 Run Command](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/run-command/) rather than try to automate an SSH connection.

> Amazon EC2 Run Command provides a simple way of automating common administrative tasks like executing Shell scripts and commands on Linux, running PowerShell commands on Windows, installing software or patches, and more. Amazon EC2 Run Command allows you to execute these commands across multiple instances and provides visibility into the results, making it easy to manage configuration change across fleets of instances.

Your instances would need the Amazon EC2 Systems Manager (SSM) agent installed. See: [Installing SSM Agent](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ssm-agent.html#sysman-install-ssm-agent)

You would then run commands on Amazon EC2 instances [from the management console](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/rc-console.html), [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or via an API call.

The `send` command does not accept tags as input. However, you could first perform a `list-instances` command to search for instances by tag, then pass the `instance-ids` to the `send` command. See: [AWS CLI `send-command`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/send-command.html)

Comment: I am trying to execute some bash script on the basis of some tags present on EC2 instances. Would that be possible? If yes, then can you please brief about it?

Comment: I've updated my Answer. You can't select by Tag, but you could find instances by tag first, then run commands on them. Have a read of the manual -- it's a very robust way of running commands on multiple EC2 instances.

Comment: I want an automated solution, not manual. If you can help me out in my boto script to ssh using private IP, that would be a great help

Comment: The EC2 Run Command can be fully automated, either via the CLI or API (eg with Boto). It is much more scalable and reliable than using SSH to connect to each instance individually. It is also better at handling failure and providing back logs.