# Running python script via AWS lambda on EC2

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am using paramiko package in lambda to run python script on EC2 and get the output back in Lambda. I was under the impression that when I run the python script from lambda then the scipt gets executed on EC2 and returns the output to lambda. But this is not happening. I installed pandas on my EC2 and ran a simple python script with import pandas. Lambda gives me an error that pandas module not found. But why do lambda need pandas module. Shouldn't it just take the output from EC2 ?

Below is my lambda function

```
import boto3
import paramiko

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # boto3 client
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

    # getting instance information
    describeInstance = client.describe_instances()


    hostPublicIP=["59.53.239.242"]
    # fetchin public IP address of the running instances
    # for i in describeInstance['Reservations']:
    #     for instance in i['Instances']:
    #         if instance["State"]["Name"] == "running":
    #             hostPublicIP.append(instance['PublicIpAddress'])

    print(hostPublicIP)

    # downloading pem filr from S3
    s3_client.download_file('paramiko','ec2key.pem', '/tmp/file.pem')

    # reading pem file and creating key object
    key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("/tmp/file.pem")
    # an instance of the Paramiko.SSHClient
    ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    # setting policy to connect to unknown host
    ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    host=hostPublicIP[0]
    print("Connecting to : " + host)
    # connecting to server
    ssh_client.connect(hostname=host, username="ubuntu", pkey=key)
    print("Connected to :" + host)

    # command list
    commands = ["python3 test.py"]

    # executing list of commands within server
    for command in commands:
        print("Executing {command}")
        stdin , stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(command)
        print(stdout.read())
        print(stderr.read())

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Thanks!')
    }
```

Below is my test.py

```
import pandas
result = 2+2
print(result)
```

Comment: Using SSH from an AWS Lambda function to run something on an Amazon EC2 instance isn't a very good architecture. See: [SSH to EC2 instance using boto on private IP through bastion server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44093145/174777)

Comment: are you sure you have pandas module available to ec2-user in the ec2 box?. Could it be that the msg is coming from host, and nothing to do with your lambda per se?

Comment: @AdilHindistan I am sure pandas module is present in my ec2 box because when I run the same file directly from ec2 instance. It works fine.